# How to display inline <span> inside <div>?

Tags: html, css, block, inline

How can I display inline spans inside a div element? I would like to show them inline, and automatically regulating their sizes and the space that they take equally, depends the user's screen, and to be behind all others div elements.

```css
body { 

width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
overflow: scroll;

    .whole {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 240px;
        z-index: -1;
        position: relative;
    }

    #main { 
        background-color: #212121;
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        display: block;

    }

    #second-main { 
        background-color: #424242;
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        display: block;
    }

    #third-main { 
        background-color: #616161;
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        display: block;
    }

    #fourth-main { 
        background-color: #757575;
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "whole">
                <span id="main">
                    <p></p>
                </span>

                <span id="second-main">
                    <p></p>
                </span>

                <span id="third-main">
                    <p></p>
                </span>

                <span id="fourth-main">
                    <p></p>
                </span>

                <span id="fifth-main">
                    <p></p>
                </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: inline-block instead of block? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Comment: have you considered using bootstrap? it suits your purposes perfect

Comment: Funk Doc, Tried to use block but nothing change.

Pouyan, trying to perfecting and do it with CSS, my next step is Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span>` is `inline` by default, and `<div>` is `block` by default. But in your CSS you're overwriting those default styles with `display: block` (in `#main`, etc). If you want them to resize as the screen does, and be inline, a better way overall is just to use `flexbox`:

HTML:

```
<div class="whole">
  <span id="main">
      <p></p>
  </span>
  <span id="second-main">
      <p></p>
  </span>
  <span id="third-main">
      <p></p>
  </span>
  <span id="fourth-main">
      <p></p>
  </span>
  <span id="fifth-main">
      <p></p>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.whole {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  -ms-display: flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 240px;
}

.whole > span {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

#main { 
  background-color: #212121;
}

#second-main { 
  background-color: #424242;
}

#third-main { 
  background-color: #616161;
}

#fourth-main { 
  background-color: #757575;
}
```

(you were also missing a closing CSS bracket for `body`, and your `font-size: 100%` was being overwritten in the very next line by a shorthand `font` rule)

**Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tceqx58x/**

Comment: You're missing the css for fifth-main

Comment: I'd edit my post and remove the fifth element. - pokeybit

Comment: benny - thank you very much. it works, but how can I separate the 4 boxes in two rows?

Comment: @pokeybit there are no styles for `#fifth-main`. @Petko Chakov, please review my `flexbox` solution, it is more modern than `inline` for what you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: @PetkoChakov put the ones you want in the second row inside their own `<div class="whole">`. Each `.whole` would be a row, and the spans would flex inside

Comment: awesome, glad I was able to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

To fit all in one line you need to have them the width divisible by total items, so in your case you need 20% width to fit 5 span elements in. (When using percentages be careful as margin will push elements over the actual specified percentages)

Use `display:inline-block;` for the span elements and avoid duplicated code where you assign the style in just one condition.

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.whole {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}

.whole span {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 400px;

}

#main { 
    background-color: #212121;
    background-size: cover;

}

#second-main { 
    background-color: #424242;
    background-size: cover;
}

#third-main { 
    background-color: #616161;
    background-size: cover;
}

#fourth-main { 
    background-color: #757575;
    background-size: cover;
}

#fifth-main { 
    background-color: #dddddd;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class = "whole">
            <span id="main">
                <p></p>
            </span><span id="second-main">
                <p></p>
            </span><span id="third-main">
                <p></p>
            </span><span id="fourth-main">
                <p></p>
            </span><span id="fifth-main">
                <p></p>
            </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block`, as well as reduce width to 20% to fit all spans in whole class in span elements.